# Randomly lost data on activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a weird problem with activeadmin. Randomly and unexpectedly some data on a resource not showed (like it has benn empty in DB). When I check the DB, all data it is on db and it is correct.

Also the data when take some .json resource is empty too.

The only solution I found for this problem is restart nginx, but it is a problem because the client not see the information on the system.

I check the logs, but I do not see any relevant information. Is there any way to get information about it for solve this kind of problems?

System versions:
Rails 5.1.3 
ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-linux]
nginx/1.10.3 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.4

Finally I found the problem but I do not understand what is wrong on it....
This are the involucrated files:
https://gist.github.com/cpfarher/bfde79dd9c3772575b03712c0a397110

The problem occured when you open the route: lines/1/edit action. After open it, data on https://gist.github.com/cpfarher/bfde79dd9c3772575b03712c0a397110#file-admin_recipe-rb is not showed.

If you change de sentence "select distinct" on line:
https://gist.github.com/cpfarher/bfde79dd9c3772575b03712c0a397110#file-recipe_fail-rb-L10
all works fine, the field on https://gist.github.com/cpfarher/bfde79dd9c3772575b03712c0a397110#file-admin_recipe-rb-L13 showed ok. But, if you use the clause with select distinct, the field it is not showed....

On the other hand if you use the file: https://gist.github.com/cpfarher/bfde79dd9c3772575b03712c0a397110#file-recipe_ok-rb instead of https://gist.github.com/cpfarher/bfde79dd9c3772575b03712c0a397110#file-recipe_fail-rb all works fine.... :|

Comment: Are you able to try a different app server, eg. puma?

Comment: @PiersC yes, the problem was in production and also in development with puma! :|... But finally I found the problem, but I do not understand what is wrong! I edit the original post with more details!, Thank you...